# PHP not updating mySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I tried adding location data to a mysql database through my php server from the TripTracker Android App. this in php but it still isn't working. Please help me with it.
With the for loop, it creates an empty row in the database.
When i remove it, it does not work at all.

```
<?php
    $json = $_GET['locations'];//get the post you sent...
    //$data = $_GET['locations'];
    $data = json_decode($json); //decode the json formatted string...
    $data = array();
    print_r($data);
    echo ($data);
    //foreach ($data as $x=>$loc){
    $loctime = $data->time;
    $latitude = $data->latitude;
    $longitude = $data->longitude;

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("gpscoordinates", $con);
    $loctime = $_POST['time'];
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO  `gpscoordinates`.`locations`
            (`id`, `loctime`, `latitude`, `longitude`)
            VALUES (NULL, '$loctime', '$latitude', '$longitude')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_close($con);
    //}
    //echo json_encode($variable);
?>
```

Below is a working Rails equivalent.

```
params[:locations].each do |x,loc|
    l = Tripcoord.new
    l.created_at = Time.at(loc[:time].to_i)
    l.latitude = loc[:latitude]
    l.longitude = loc[:longitude]
    l.save!
  end
```

Comment: $data = array(); you redefined $data to an empty array

Comment: 1)sql injection
2)id field might be auto increment
3)check is there any data in array..

Answer (score 0):

You set the values from the $_POST array:

```
$loctime = $_POST['time'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
```

But your data is from a $_GET array?

```
 $json = $_GET['locations'];
```

Am I missing something, because that obviously is not going to work.

Change

```
$_GET['locations'] to $_POST['locations']
```

(or vice versa, as the case may be).  Not to mention,

```
$data = array();
```

Would empty out the values if there were anything in $_POST anyway.

I hope I'm not completely misunderstanding....